# Should I use a unique_ptr with an array type, or a vector?

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

I've been out of C++ for years, last time I used it was back in gamedesign before C++11. I see all these new pointer types which seem great. But I'm unsure when and how to use them. In the old days I would create a buffer like this:

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(bufferSize, sizeof(char));
```

It's not pretty and I'm pretty sure even back then new/delete was already a thing in C++, but I never learned about them in that time. I don't think raw pointers should be used if avoidable, so I'm trying to get used to writing this now:

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer;
buffer = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(bufferSize);
```

But this raises the question, should I just map the old raw pointers to `unique_ptr` like this? There's also `std::vector`, which seems like a much more natural fit for any array. Should I use a vector instead? Are there rules of thumb for when to use one or the other (for arrays)?

To add some more specific information, I'm making a game and I'm setting up a screenbuffer to draw to, I'm starting with ASCII and will likely move on to pixels somewhere in the future. The buffer size will never have to change at runtime, but it would be nice to be able to play with the screen size a bit during development so that's why I'm not simply declaring a fixed-length array (my bufferSize is actually two consts multiplied; screenWidth and screenHeight). This is just a prototype, it doesn't have to be scalable or deployable, but I still want to use this chance to learn to write better C++.

Comment: Rule of thumb: don’t write C, if you want to write C++. Very special corner cases aside, usually std::vector or any other modern STL container is the way to go.

Comment: @Simon Is std::unique_ptr not C++?

Comment: unique_pte is, but C array is not.

Comment: @Simon A native array most certainly is C++. Using a `std::array` is necessary if you write generic code (native array of length zero is non-standard), or have to treat the whole array as a first-class-object. Otherwise, don't bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(TYPE)` has been a bad idea in C and C++ since forever, assuming you could use `sizeof *pointer`. The problem is that it duplicates the type-Information without adding a check.

In C, casting a `void*` is also a bad idea, as overriding the language should only be done where and when necessary after careful consideration.

And finally, `malloc()` only accepts one argument, you want to multiply there instead. Your compiler should warn you though.

Next, this:

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(char));
```

Is not quite equivalent to the following, barring the allocator used and the automatic management of the buffer:

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
auto buffer = std::make_unique<unsigned char[]>(bufferSize);
```

The additional difference is the value-initialization, the latter does it, the former refrains from it.

Is that significant?
We cannot say, it depends on the specific circumstances. Maybe you actually want that initialization, or the compiler can optimize it out.

Or maybe the following matches your needs better:

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer(new unsigned char[bufferSize]);
```

Alternative using C++20 [`std::make_unique_default_init()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
uint bufferSize = 1024;
auto buffer = std::make_unique_default_init<unsigned char[]>(bufferSize);
```

Anyway, unless you use something like directly above, or you have to pass the buffer on to code expecting a `new`ed up buffer, `std::vector` is likely simpler and is liable to be optimized down to the same code.

Comment: As C++ is currently defined, the version using `malloc` apparently has UB. You have to do a placement `new` on each `int` in the memory you allocated to get defined behavior. AFAIK, this has no practical effect though (doesn't change behavior with any known compiler).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` for a buffer of statically-unknown size.

You *can* also use a `std::array<unsigned char, SIZE>` for a buffer of statically-known size, but you don't have to.

A vector is fairly easy to use.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(ScreenWidth * ScreenHeight);
// use buffer.data() as you would previously use a unsigned char *
```

Don't use `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>`, `new`, `new[]` or `malloc`, as using them is more verbose, isn't any more performant than equivalent use of `vector`, and requires careful inspection to ensure you haven't mistakenly got undefined behaviour. For example, your use of `malloc` didn't create any `unsigned char`s, so any use is undefined behaviour.

It may be worth declaring a type alias if you go for a `std::array`:

```
constexpr unsigned ScreenWidth = 1920;
constexpr unsigned ScreenHeight = 1080;

using ScreenBuffer = std::array<unsigned char, ScreenWidth * ScreenHeight>;
```

Comment: I upvoted for mentioned `std::array`. I think the answer could be much stronger if "Don't use std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>, new or malloc." was more than a bare assertion.